# sent coins to wallet address, but bitcoin-qt shows no balance

Tags: bitcoind

Coin was sent in March 2014, to an address I specified, from coinbase to bitcoin-qt, which I think is associated with blockchain.info.  Since then, I have installed a new hard drive and the wallet.dat from my backup was put in place of the one in the appdata/roaming/bitcoin. I had tried salvagewallet and rescan after finding that no balance or transactions were showing.
I see the transactions to this address in coinbase and the address still has a balance in blockchain.info, but I have noticed DIFFERENT,unrecognized receiving addresses in bitcoin-qt.

is there another way to restore my old wallet.dat?